# git alias to delete local and remote

Tags: git, shell, command, alias, git-alias

I'm trying to write an alias to delete both a local and remote branch at the same time, but I can't figure out why the syntax is not working.  In `~/.gitconfig`, I've tried the following aliases, but each produces the same result, which is unexpected:

```
[alias]
     nuke = !sh -c 'git branch -D $1 && git push origin :$1'
```

and

```
[alias]
     nuke = !git branch -D $1 && git push origin :$1
```

both produce:

```
$> git branch
  * master
  mybranch
$> git nuke mybranch
Everything up-to-date
$> git branch
  * master
  mybranch
```

Switching the order of the commands produces a different result, but also not entirely what I'm looking for:

```
[alias]
    nuke = !git push origin :$1 && git branch -D $1

...

$> git branch
  * master
  mybranch
$> git nuke mybranch
Everything up-to-date
Deleted branch mybranch (was d719895)
$> git branch
  * master
$> git push origin :mybranch
To git@github.com:biegel/repo.git
 - [deleted]         mybranch
```

When I run that command directly on the shell, it works nicely:

```
$> git branch
* master
  mybranch
$> git branch -D mybranch && git push origin :mybranch
Deleted branch mybranch (was d719895
To git@github.com:biegel/repo.git
 - [deleted]         mybranch
$> git branch
* master
```

I've tried creating an alias in `~/.bashrc`, using `git push origin --delete $1` and using a shell function with `!f() { };` and nothing seems to take!

I'm ready to give up.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can make this work just fine.  You just need to add a missing command name at the end of your definition.  The command name will become `$0` and everything after will get assigned to `$1`, `$2`, etc.  In this case, I simply used `-` as the command name:

```
[alias]
     nuke = !sh -c 'git branch -D $1 && git push origin :$1' -
```

From the command line, switch to another branch, then run the command:

```
git nuke branch-name
```

---

Alternately… If you are unable to add the above to your `.gitconfig` file for some reason, but have access to the `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc… you can add the following:

```
git config --global alias.nuke '!sh -c "git branch -D $1 && git push origin :$1" -'
```

You can read more about `sh` and how it's expected to work [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html).

Comment: This is a good answer, but the explanation is incorrect. When calling `sh`, the first positional argument is the name of the script being executed. (The shell puts this value into `$0`.) When `-c` is used, there is no script, so — by convention — `-` is used in its place.

Comment: @smammy You're absolutely right.  Updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a bin called `git-nuke` and place it in a directory anywhere on your `$PATH`, you will achieve the same effect.  The advantage with this approach is the ability to write a command with a bit more clarity and robustness.

Example, in my bash profile I have: `export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"`.

And in `~/.bin/git-nuke`, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

#
# git nuke <branch-name>
#
# Delete a branch (irrespective of its merged status) and
# remove from origin.
#

echo "Nuking $1 ..."

if git show-branch "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  git branch -D "$1"
else
  echo "No local branch to delete"
fi

git remote prune origin
if git show-branch "origin/$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo "Deleting remote $1 ..."
  git push origin ":$1"
else
  echo "No remote branch to delete"
fi
```

Comment: Another advantage of this is you can add autocompletion.

Comment: Can I make git complete this as a new subcommand `nuke` as if it where defined as an alias or do I have to type `git-nuke`? in the shell?

Comment: The `git-mycmd` trick means you now have a `mycmd` subcommand and will be called via `git mycmd` and tab completion will work with using `git my[tab]`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$1` in an alias. Create a script called `git-nuke` somewhere in your path so you have access to proper shell scripting.

You could also just install [git-extras](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras). That’s a script compilation that contains the `git delete-branch` script, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the pointer.  I'll probably go with git-extras.

Comment: Please see [jszakmeister's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16740731/456814), you **can** use `$1` in an alias.

Comment: While jszakmeister’s answer is an nice solution indeed, you still can not use `$1` in an alias. `sh` is doing the `$1` handling there. The arguments to an alias are always appended to it.